# login form validation in android before implementing method login

Tags: android-studio

I need help to filter empty edittext in login activity before trying to call method and execute query in mysql.. I am new in android development and getting really lost.. I followed a tutorial that works well in registration and login but no filtering or validation.  Sad to say, I was not able to fully understand the steps on how each function / method are running.. I will appreciate if you can give me a link to a better page for a good tutorial which is not obsolete or have deprecated libraries.. I am using android 1.5.

I've been searching google and threads here but I could not find solution that is understandable by a newbie in android..

Here is the code of my Main.java which handles log in

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText name, password;
String Name, Password;
Context ctx=this;
String NAME=null, PASSWORD=null, EMAIL=null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_name);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_password);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}



public void main_register(View v){
    startActivity(new Intent(this,Register.class));
}
public void main_login(View v){
    Name = name.getText().toString();
    Password = password.getText().toString();
    BackGround b = new BackGround();
    b.execute(Name, Password);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.main_login:

            break;

    }
}

class BackGround extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String name = params[0];
        String password = params[1];
        String data="";
        int tmp;

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/BirdBreedingManagement/scripts/login.php");
            String urlParams = "name="+name+"&password="+password;

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            os.write(urlParams.getBytes());
            os.flush();
            os.close();

            InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            while((tmp=is.read())!=-1){
                data+= (char)tmp;
            }

            is.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            return data;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        String err=null;

        try {
            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(s);
            JSONObject user_data = root.getJSONObject("user_data");
            NAME = user_data.getString("name");
            PASSWORD = user_data.getString("password");
            EMAIL = user_data.getString("email");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            err = "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
        }

        Intent i = new Intent(ctx, Home.class);
        i.putExtra("name", NAME);
        i.putExtra("password", PASSWORD);
        i.putExtra("email", EMAIL);
        i.putExtra("err", err);
        startActivity(i);

    }
}
```

And here is the php script
    try{

```
    //$username = "jeel";
    //$pssword = "23456";


    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
    $pssword =  filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password');

    if($username == "" ){
        $results = "Invalid Entry";
        echo json_encode(array("user_data"=>$results));
    }else{
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * '
                        . 'FROM users1 '
                        . 'WHERE name = :uname AND password = :password ');
        $stmt->bindParam(':uname', $username);
        $stmt->bindParam(':password', $pssword);
        $stmt->execute();
        $results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if($results > 0 ){
            $response = array();
            echo json_encode(array("user_data"=>$results));
        } else{
            $results = "No Record Found";
            echo json_encode(array("user_data"=>$results));
        }
    }

 }catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to check the `username` and `password` fields empty or not before running the `AsyncTask` to get data from php. Modify the `main_login(View v)` method as below

```
 public void main_login(View v){
        Name = name.getText().toString();
        Password = password.getText().toString();
        if(Name==null || Password==null){
         // can alert the user that either one of username or the password is empty by

       Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Username or the Password is empty",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // in here you can restart the current activity
        startActivity(this,Main.class);
        finish();  // to destroy the current activity

        }
        else{
        BackGround b = new BackGround();
        b.execute(Name, Password);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you.. It lead me to solve my issue.. I modified you code as I was not able to make this line work..Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Username or the Password is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); and some adjustment in stopping the activity.

Comment: in the line `Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Username or the Password is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); ` the first parameter is used to pass the `context` to the `Toast`. you can send the `context` through `this`, `getActivity()` and `getApplicationContext()` Sorry for not mentioning it ealier

Comment: Since my answer really helped you, I would be glad If you can `vote` my answer `up` or accept my answer as the correct. Because at present I am unable to post any question in this site, as I have reached the maximum question limit for my current reputation, so I am in a little hurry of increasing my reputation to get back in line :)

Comment: yeah, I fogot it, But you can accept my answer as the correct one by ticking the correct sign appear next to my answer, from that you will also receive `2` reputation for accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Kasun Siyambalapitiya lead me to make the code perform as expected with some adjustment made.. I am posting it here to share to others who's also looking for a code which they can try if the answer of Kasun didn't fit in their requirement..

```
`public void main_login(View v){
    Name = name.getText().toString();
    Password = password.getText().toString();

    if(name.getText().length()==0){


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Please Enter your name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        startActivity(intent);
    }else{
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        startActivity(intent);
        BackGround b = new BackGround();
        b.execute(Name, Password);
    }
}`
```

I remove the finish command to avoid the application from closing and reopening.